# Sending a date into DB along with form details

Tags: php

How simple is it to send a date into a database along with the information submitted from a form.

If i create a new column for the date in the table, how do i then submit that information secretley

Comment: `INSERT INTO table ( my_date, my_data ) VALUES ( $date, $data );`

Comment: what does 'secretly' means? i didnt get it.

Answer (score 0):

You add a date the same way you add any other data into the database.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3)
```

Comment: sorry i think i mean more like a time/date stamp... the date is added to the DB when the form was submitted

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have the data stored as a variable, obviously? Why not just insert it into the correct field of the database? If you want the current timestamp, you can use `time()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Date type within MySQL for example you will need to send it a unix timestamp for the data to be stored correctly.
But yes sending a date to the database is perfectly possible using PHP.

Comment: i have a date column in my table with timestamp type, will that automatically store the date or do i need to send a variable to it?